# basic slice of numpy array indexing would not trigger IndexError?

Tags: python, numpy

Does doing basic indexing in ndarray via slice have build-in boundary check?

In the following example, there is no IndexError being raised.

example code:

```
x=numpy.arange(3)
print( 'x[6:9]',x[6:9] )
```

output:

```
x[6:9]=[]
```

Comment: [heres the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951107/why-pythons-list-slicing-doesnt-produce-index-out-of-bound-error)

Comment: @IsraelAbebe thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why substring slicing index out of range works in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490058/why-substring-slicing-index-out-of-range-works-in-python)